# No controls showing upon opening form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I've made several projects in the past that open forms as dialogs, but this one doesn't seem to be working.

CODE:

```
    private void aboutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var ab = new MDTAboutBox())
        {
            ab.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

RESULT:
[image: Animation]

But the designer looks like this...
[image: Designer]

Comment: Did you call InitializeComponent as first thing in your form constructor?

Comment: You probably messed up the ctor.  Hard to tell from a picture

Comment: It's probably in the code for `MDTAboutBox`.

Comment: *Facepalm* I knew there was something missing... I forgot the constructor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly, I forgot to add the form constructor in the `MDTAboutBox` code... All works as expected now.

[image]